# OnClick event is not triggered inside map function

Tags: reactjs, dictionary

```
     <input
        className="w-1/2 border  p-2 rounded-l-full"
        type="text"
        value={searchQuery}
        onChange={(e) => setSearchQuery(e.target.value)}
        onFocus={() => setShowSuggestions(true)}
        onBlur={() => setShowSuggestions(false)}
      />
      <button
        onClick={(e) => handleClick(e.target.value)}
      >
        
      </button>
    </div>

    {showSuggestions && (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {suggestions.map((s) =>(<li 
              onClick={()=>console.log("hello list")}
              key={s}>
                {s}
              </li>
              )
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )}
  </div>
```

I want to print Hello list in console but not getting when i am clicking on the list.I have tried all way .But couldn't find what is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely related to event propagation and bubbling. When you click on the `<li>` element, the click event is triggered, but it may also propagate to the parent elements, including the `<button>` element that wraps the input. As a result, the handleClick function from the  click event is executed instead of the onClick function inside the `<li>` element.

To prevent this event propagation and ensure that the onClick inside the `<li>` element is triggered, you can use the e.stopPropagation() method inside the onClick event of the `<li>` element.

Here's the updated code:

```
<input
  className="w-1/2 border p-2 rounded-l-full"
  type="text"
  value={searchQuery}
  onChange={(e) => setSearchQuery(e.target.value)}
  onFocus={() => setShowSuggestions(true)}
  onBlur={() => setShowSuggestions(false)}
/>
<button onClick={(e) => handleClick(e.target.value)}></button>
</div>

{showSuggestions && (
  <div>
    <ul>
      {suggestions.map((s) => (
        <li
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.stopPropagation(); // Prevent event propagation
            console.log("hello list");
          }}
          key={s}
        >
          {s}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </div>
)}
</div>
```

With this change, the e.stopPropagation() method will prevent the click event from bubbling up to the parent elements, and the onClick function inside the `<li>` element should now be triggered as expected, printing "Hello list" to the console.

Hope this will help you!!!

Comment: no,it didn't work.

Comment: Here are a few additional steps you can take to troubleshoot:  -> **Check for Overlapping Elements:** Make sure that there are no overlapping elements that might be capturing the click event before it reaches the <li> element.  -> **Check for Global Event Listeners:** If you have global event listeners or other event-related logic in your application, they might interfere with the expected behavior.